# Why are Pokémon stacked on top of each other whenever I start?

Tags: pokemon-go

[image]

I have installed the game recently, and in the start, this happens. Due to this, I can't choose my starter. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 8):

You need to activate the GPS position.

Comment: From the question, it's not clear that this is their problem.