# I cannot choose my first Pokemon in Pokemon Go

Tags: pokemon-go

[image: standing on top of the starters]

[image: more standing on top of the starters]

I cannot choose my first Pokemon in Pokemon Go. How can I fix this?

Comment: Duplicate of http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/290449/165917

Comment: @Kent I agree but unfortunately, we can't close a question as a dupe if the original doesn't have an upvoted answer or accepted answer.

Comment: To the user who flagged this as opinion based, this is not a primarily opinion-based question.

Answer (score 4):

Unless you are standing in a desert (or a huge field ?), this is probably a bug due to your **phone geolocation** : make sure you enabled geolocation data and you have a correct internet connection on your phone. The game tends to be laggy and buggy in general if you have a poor quality connection.

Answer (score -1):

This can be fixed. Try using the following ways-

1)Have a strong internet

2)Geo location set to 'high accuracy'

and if this fails-

Be sure to have the above two requirements. Now be in an open space and try running, Now the pokemon would disappear for a second and reappear. Do this until you see a pikachu `Yes not kidding!`, and this should fix your issue.